# CSS: website logo not appearing in IE11

Tags: css, header, internet-explorer-11

My website renders perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. However, in IE11 the logo does not appear in the desktop version but does in the mobile version. So, must be something to do with the CSS?

I have this in my header.php:

```
<!-- LOGO BLOCK STARTS HERE -->
<div id="logo">
<div align="center"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><hr class="stylelogo"></a><br />
<span class="current-date">Mywebsite.com | <?php echo date_i18n('j F Y', time()); ?></span>
</div><!-- end #logo -->
  </div>
<!-- MOBILE LOGO BLOCK STARTS HERE -->
  <div id="mobilelogo">
<div align="center"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/logo.png"></a><br />
<span class="current-date">Mywebsite.com | <?php echo date_i18n('j F Y', time()); ?></span>
</div></div><!-- end #mobilelogo -->
<!-- LOGO BLOCK ENDS HERE --><br />
```

and this in my CSS:

```
#masthead {
  display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
#mobilelogo {display:none;}

@media all and (max-width: 32.5em) {
#logo {display: none; }
#mobilelogo{display:block;}
}

hr.stylelogo {
    border: 0; 
    height: 1px; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
hr.stylelogo:after {
    content: url(http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/logo.png);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -14px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 16px; }
```

So, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is always a bore isn't it. Anyway, there were some answers here. Specifically, I added a script into the header file kindly provided by [Marko Kazhich](http://marxo.me/target-ie-in-css/). Then I just tinkered with the CSS. Bit of a mess but it's better. Some things couldn't really resolve so I lost a little bit of the niceties in my original. The cost to those that use IE.